# trying to install ruby package to Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid box, cant install rubygems

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, linode

Were following this guide [right here](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/ubuntu-10.04-lucid) trying to set up hosting for our Rails app on a Linode Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx box.

trying to run `cd /opt/rubygems-1.5.1/`

`ruby setup.rb` to install Ruby on the Ubuntu box, having errors installing this

overall error: `bash:/zsh: ruby: command not found`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you don't have ruby properly installed. Try

```
apt-get install ruby
```

And see if it helps. If you don't want to use the package manager, make sure the your *ruby* binary is in the system's PATH. Example:

```
export PATH=<path to ruby>;$PATH
```

Comment: Post the output of 'which ruby' so we can try to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use RVM ( ruby version manager ).

Here is a very good tutorial to install it : [ryan bigg blog - ubuntu & rvm](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/)

Comment: we've had RVM installed on our OS X we just werent differentiating terminal control of environments, i.e. thought we were controlling our root directory when really we were trying to install things on the Ubuntu box using direct SSH access.